# How to configure integration in AWS Gateway HTTP API to invoke lambda with Alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway-v2

I have AWS API Gateway (v2). The URL contains "execute-api", that means I am using an HTTP API. The API has integration with AWS Lambda as backend. I have configured the lambda to use provisioned concurrency. As per the aws documentation

> Provisioned Concurrency is not supported on the unpublished version
> of the function ($LATEST). Ensure your client application is not
> pointing to $LATEST before configuring provisioned concurrency.

In this scenario, the client application is an API. The API must point to a specific lambda alias for provision concurrency. However, the AWS Console does not provide an option to specify the alias in the lambda ARN. Normally, the alias can be specified by adding ":aliasname" to the end of the lambda ARN, but doing so results in the API Gateway console displaying "No matching lambda functions." Additionally, in the Lambda console, an error is displayed stating that `the trigger is invalid because the API with the specified ID does not include a route with the path "/*" and the integration ARN specified.`

Questions
1> Does API need to point specific lambda Alias for provisioning concurrency to work?
2>If yes, then how do I point API to Lambda Alias?

[image]

[image]